# Language model to score sentence?

Tags: nlp, recurrent-neural-network

I have a corpus with bad sentences and good ones. I need to train a RNN language model to give quality score to every sentence. I tried [tensorflow ptb](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb) model. It works during training. But the project doesn't give much info about how to use the model. I ran into all sorts of problem when trying to modify it to score sentence.
Is there an example showing how to use.the model?

Also, another project  [IMDB comment classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_text_classification) caught my eyes. Is it a good idea to use that model to classify good sentences and bad ones?

Comment: Have you seen this https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/recurrent

Comment: What goal are you trying to achieve with your scoring/classification?

Comment: To tell bad sentence (with wrong grammer or simply random characters) from real ones. I've checked out the tutorial but I don't know how to adapt the model to do the job. The tutorial says nothing about loading and using the model.